# How to bevel this cylinder extruded inset face?

Tags: bevel

I would like to shape this thing from 2001 A Space Odyssey, it's a connector to pressurize the suit

[image: 2001]

I began to add a cylinder, inset the top face, extrude it but now I don't know how to bevel it to make it rounder like in the picture above

[image: blender]

Sorry I couldn't find a better quality pic from this connector in the movie.

EDIT : here's a gif of my issue, I followed Sander's instructions but it results in that (as you can see, it doesn't bevel at all, but it bevels right if I try on a simple cylinder edges) : [image: gifcylinderbevel]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: so what does it give if you bevel? And in what way it doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: I'm really a noob with Blender even if I'm learning everyday, in this case I don't know "what to bevel", my first thought was to bevel the edges between the cylinder and its extruded face but it doesn't work, it makes ugly changes that I don't understand

Comment: in that case please show the result of your bevel

Comment: It's not that I don't want to, but I did a lot of tests with a lot of different parameters, and I'll have to show you all the screenshots of every tests... The only thing that I want to do, is what this man is doing at this part of the video https://youtu.be/3HDPqYVNvHs?t=381 but it's so fast I can't understand what he's doing... Is there a tutorial about that ? Thanks

Comment: He has given a Subdivision Surface to his object and he's doing some Ctrl B, if it doesn't work well for you it may be because you have inverted normals, or you haven't applied the scale in Object mode, but it's hard to say if you don't show any image or if you don't share your object, please share here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I did the "push all the buttons" technique and it worked lol. Instead of a cylinder, I've used a sphere that I "squished" along the Z axis near 0, then I selected the area in the middle with a face selection and I pulled it upwards. then I selected the edges between the flat area and the pulled faces and I used the "width percent" tab in the bevel menu, and I was able to repeat the process with Shift+R until it was curvy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to apply object's scale because bevel is done to object's mesh that is then scaled according the scale. In object mode while in 3d viewport hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>s</kbd> to choose scale form the Apply menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know the difference between mesh and object x)

Answer (score 2):

To bevel any edge, select that entire edge, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

To highlight the whole outer circle, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> whilst clicking an edge. At any time you can also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to add the next thing you select to the current selection (if you want to bevel multiple edges at once, for instance). Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to apply the bevel (or use the bevel tool) and move your mouse around to adjust it. After applying the operation by clicking again, a frame should pop up in the lower left which gives you a bunch of options to mess with.

[image]

Furthermore, to make it look more like the result of the video you linked in a comment, you should select "Shade Smooth" when right clicking your shape in Object Mode.

**Edit: Actually, I think I know what is going on in the GIF you added.** There is a difference between scaling things in *Object Mode* and scaling them in *Edit Mode*. It looks like you have your Object scaled down along the Z axis (flattened) in *Object Mode*, and so any modification you apply in *Edit Mode* is also flattened.

Go to *Object Mode*, select your object, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the context menu on the side, then go to the *Item* tab and **make sure that the scale of you object is set to 1.0 on all axes**. If I'm correct it should make your shape get really really tall all of the sudden. Go back into *Edit Mode*, only *then* can you select everything and scale it back down along the Z axis. Then the bevel should work fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial and for your time, thank you !

Comment: Hello, I edited my original question to add a gif because it doesn't seem to work the way it do in yours :/

Comment: @Dodecahedron can you upload your blender file to https://blend-exchange.com/ and share the link? Something about the geometry of the shape you are starting with seems to be messed up.

Comment: @Dodecahedron Actually, I'm pretty sure I know what your issue is, I edited the answer above. If that didn't work for you I'd still like the blender file.

Comment: You were right to be sure about that ! It works and you just teach me scaling in object mode isn't the same thing in edit mode, I didn't know that, thank you !!